# Debugging Angular 7 in Visual Studio 2017 breakpoint not hit

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-core

Have started a asp.net core 2.2 app with Angular 7.  If I set a breakpoint in the TS code, its not hit when I change the dropdown value.  What do I need to look at?

in the template

```
          <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="sel1" name="sellist1" (change)="selectTerminal($event.target.value)">
        <option>Val1</option>
        <option>Val2</option>
        <option>Val3</option>
        <option>Val4</option>

      </select>
```

method in my component

```
  selectTerminal(event: any)
  {    
    this.deliveryDate = event.target.value;
  }
```

Comment: Debug in a browser or make sure you have the chrome debugging extension for VS Code.

Comment: Im not using VS Code, but rather Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I understand that. You can’t do it in VS as far as I’m aware.

Comment: Chrome has a very nice debugger and the code is located under the sources/webpack

Comment: Try putting debugger in ts file.

Comment: @theMayer - Yes, I was ok with that but it was bugging the crap out of me that I knew I had done this before with an earlier version of Angular.  See my resolution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that, while ng build , ng serve both reported no issues, as well as a build of the .net project working as expected, I discovered numerous Typescript-related issues on the error list tab in VS.  After following a few other threads, what seems to have fixed those issues was 
(1) deleting my node_modules and /dist folders 
(2) starting a new .net core app w/angular template project (so as to comapre to mine) and comparing the tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json files - both with the default Angular 6 example AND after upgrading this dummy project to Angular 7. 
Turns out, somehow my TS compiler options had changed to es6 and es2018
(3) Closing VS down and re-opening, however I think the problem was already solved by the 2 things above

Now I can hit F5 and hit breakpoints in TS code as expected.